# Discord.py - Bot does not react and not sending messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

everyone!
**What I Want:** Recently decided to learn discord.py, but faced a problem from the start. Namely, I wanted to code the simplest bot that can send back "hello" after it sees "hello" from a user.
In order to make it, I coded the following:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
channel = bot.get_channel(1069982959458848801)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("BOT IS ONLINE")

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
  if msg.content == "hello":
      await msg.channel.send("hello")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**What I Did:** Initially, I thought the problem with intents(developer portal is fine also, all three intents are turned on), but then I realised that console does not contain any error messages. Then I double checked my code and everything is fine I suppose.

So, would really appreciate your help with this question. Thank you in advance!

> User: hello
> Bot: hello

Comment: You thought right, the problem **is** related to intents. You didn't enable them in code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need the  `Message.content` intent. As explained in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#need-message-content-intent).

Since msg.content will otherwise be an empty string according to this [doc source](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content). You could check by trying to print msg.content, before and after the if statement. Then you will see if the content is right and if the if statement produces the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

In `discord.Intents.default()` `message_content` intent set to false , and `msg.content` is always an empty string ([message content docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content)). You need to add

```py
intents.message_content = True
```

or use

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
```

That's a simplest way to fix that

Comment: There's no need to enable all intents if you don't need them. Enable only the ones you plan on using.